# How to PSQL query for jsonb column with nested array to contain string

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a table that has a jsonb `foo` with below nested structure

```
foo: {"bar":[{"baz":["special string"]}]}
```

I want to query in psql for all records whose `foo.bar` can contain an object with the array value at `baz` containing the `"special string"`.

The farthest I've gotten is below but it's not exactly comprehensive like I need it to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE foo->'bar'->0->'baz' = '["special string"]';
```

Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. Did you mean `:` instead of `=>`?

Comment: How exactly do you want to treat the arrays? Do you only want to match rows where the *first* element of the `bar` array has a `baz` array that consists of only the single string? Do you want them to be contained in at an arbitrary position in the array?

Comment: Where any element has `baz` array that includes the string

Comment: @Bergi yes I mean `:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either the `@>` "[contains structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT)" operator

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE foo @> '{"bar": [{"baz": ["special string"]}]}';
```

or a [jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) with the `@?` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE foo @? 'strict $.bar[*] ? (@.baz[*] == "special string")';
```

Comment: @Zegarek Whoops! I've still not gotten the hang of "*An attempt to access a non-existent member of an object or element of an array results in a structural error*", while I prefer strict mode in general. Fixed now - `exists` or `?` can be used to ignore the error that would occur if the `bar` array contained any objects without a `.baz` property.

Comment: +1, thanks for addressing that. The comment no longer applies, so I removed it and moved the `lax` thing and the demo to a separate answer as a supplement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with some variability in the structure of the `jsonb` values and you don't want to tolerate it, `strict` mode [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196582/5298879) by [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) will skip the mismatched ones. The patter using `strict` and `@>` example only matches **four** of the examples below (1,4,5,6) - which might be preferable.

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE foo @? 'lax $.bar[*].baz[*] ? (@ == "special string")';
```

If you *do* want to tolerate some variance, [the default `lax` mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#STRICT-AND-LAX-MODES) won't mind if you're not dealing with an array anywhere in the (sub)path you specified, or it will reach down a few array dimensions deeper on its own if it is an array, but more complex than you outlined. That way, you can catch **nine** examples (1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11) below - which might or might not be desired, but could be useful for other purposes.

It's possible to express the same rules in either mode - in `lax` you need additional filter expressions to narrow it down at the end, while in `strict` you need to explicitly handle alternative cases in filters on the spot, mid-path.

[Here's a playground:](https://dbfiddle.uk/SRq0yMVS)

```sql
create table my_table(id, foo,comments) as values
 (0,'"special string"'::jsonb,'just the target string, no structure')
,(1,'{"bar":[{"baz":["special string"]}]}'::jsonb,'primary example')
,(2,'{"key1":[{"baz":["special string"]}]}','missing `bar`')
,(3,'{"bar":[{"key1":["special string"]}]}','missing `baz`')
,(4,'{"bar":[{"baz":["special string"]},
     {"key1":0}]}'
   ,'`key1` neighbouring `bar`')
,(5,'{"bar":[{"baz":["special string"]},
             {"key1":0}],
      "key2":0}'
   ,'`key1` replacing `baz` in 2nd element of `bar`, `key1` neighbouring `bar`')
,(6,'{"bar":[{"baz":["string1",
                     "special string"]},
             {"key1":0}],
      "key2":0}'
  ,'`key1` replacing `baz` in 2nd element of `bar`, 
    `key1` neighbouring `bar`, additional element in `baz`')
,(7,'{"bar":{"baz":"special string"}}'
   ,'neither `bar` nor `baz` are arrays')
,(8,'{"bar":[{"baz":"special string"}]}'
   ,'only `bar` is an array');
```

Plus, additional layers of arrays:

```sql
insert into my_table(id, foo,comments) values
 (9,'{"bar":[{"baz":[ ["s11","s12","special string"]
                     ,["s21","s22"]
                    ]
              }]}'
   ,'`baz` is 2d')
,(10,'{"bar":[{"baz":[ [ ["s111","s112"]
                        ,["s121","s122"] ]
                      ,[ ["s211","s212","special string"]
                        ,["s221","s222"] ]
                     ]
              }]}'
    ,'`baz` is 3d')
,(11,'{"bar":[{"baz":[ [ [ ["s1111","s1112"]
                          ,["s1121","s1122"] ]
                        ,[ ["s1211","s1212"]
                          ,["s1221","s1222"] ]
                       ]
                      ,[ [ ["s2111","s2112"]
                          ,["s2121","s2122"] ]
                        ,[ ["s2211","s2212","special string"]
                          ,["s2221","s2222"] ]
                       ]
                     ]
               }]}'
    ,'`baz` is 4d')
,(11,'{"bar":[[{"baz":["special string"]}]]}',    '`bar` is 2d')
,(12,'{"bar":[[[{"baz":["special string"]}]]]}',  '`bar` is 3d')
,(13,'{"bar":[[[[{"baz":["special string"]}]]]]}','`bar` is 4d');
```